# Flutter Text overlay on Card

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to overlay a title on images in Card widget. I am trying to achieve this using Stack widget, it seems to be messing with my constraints. My original widget:

[image]

When I add Stack:

[image]

As you can see, the text appears but it destroys the layouts. Any idea to why is this happening? to my knowledge Stack is not supposed to affect any constraints(?), it should be floating on top of the existing widget.

My code:

```
 return Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 3,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kDefaultPadding / 2)),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kDefaultPadding / 2),
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          child: Image.network(widget.data.imageUrl),
        ),
      ),
      Text("Test")
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `fit: StackFit.expand` to the `Stack`:

```dart
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 3,
  shape:
  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kDefaultPadding / 2)),),
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand, // this is new
    children: [
      ClipRRect(
...
```

---

Note: Instead of `Stack` you can use a `Container` with the image set as its decoration image and the text set as its child:

```dart
Card(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 3,
  shape:
  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kDefaultPadding / 2)),),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(widget.data.imageUrl),
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(child: Text("Test"))),
  ),
...
```